# Add form in order view on adminhtml

Tags: adminhtml, backend, adminform

How i add a form in order view like this image
[image]

on click simply record the form in a database table, the information will always be seen in the own form.

Answer (score 1):

Will need to override few `.php/.phtml` files.

In `design/adminhtml/layout/your_layout.xml`

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
     <reference name="order_tab_info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                    <template>your_path_to_admin_template/info.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <block type="your_module/adminhtml_sales_order_view_yourform" name="your_name" as="your_name" template="your_path_to_admin_template/your_form.phtml"></block>
       </reference>
```

Now, you can call `$this->getChildHtml('your_name')` in `your_path_to_admin_template/info.phtml` file, anywhere you would like to.

**To call your controller action** please check `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_History.php` file. It will give you head start.

Hope this helps.